# failed combining multiple columns into one row in ms sql

Tags: sql-server

This how the code works I got this code somewhere here in stackoverflow site, I couldn't add the email address to that row it only accepts the phone numbers

```
Select distinct ST2.AlumniID, 
substring(
    (
        Select ','+ST2.contactinfo  AS [text()]
        From dbo.Alumni_contacts ST1
        Where ST1.AlumniID = ST2.AlumniID

        For XML PATH ('')
    ), 2, 10000) [Contact Info]
From dbo.Alumni_contacts ST2
```

This is the result

```
2011-0014|656-88-24,656-88-24
2011-0014|pakchaeyoung@gmail.com,pakchaeyoung@gmail.com
2012-0098|667-63-55,667-63-55
2012-0098|park.ginnie@gmail.com,park.ginnie@gmail.com
2012-0172|gutierrez88@gmail.com
```

Do you have any better and simpler query about this?

Comment: Are those real email addresses & phone numbers? I suggest you edit those (preferably by deleting the image entirely and uploading a new one) out if so.

Comment: Remove those images and add dummy sample data and expected result. Do not expose real time data in online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are referencing wrong table expression in subquery SELECT list. It should alias of the inner FROM. Try

```
... (Select ','+ ST1.contactinfo ...
```

Comment: oh my ghad, so it's just my little stupidity :(, well thank you :D